# Magento 2: get "Sort By" filter options in Rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.3.0, category-listing, sort-by-options

Need to get `Sort By List of Options` `category products list page` using Rest API.

I have checked default REST API but can't get the same.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Any have idea how to get Sort By List of Options of category products list page using Rest API.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if still it will not working.

Comment: Getting error after also add auth 
"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",

Comment: Did you set proper headers?

Comment: yes. But still getting error.

Comment: Please reauthorize token from admin and access latest consumer token. This error related to wrong token.

Comment: can you send me for reference your headers and Body details as you did in your request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98065/discussion-between-kirti-nariya-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, I think there are no any core magento API provide data of sort by option list.
So, we need to create custom API for that.

Follow this below steps for that :

> **Step 1** : create **registration.php** file at **app/code/RH/CustomAPI/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'RH_CustomAPI',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **Step 2** : create **module.php** file at **app/code/RH/CustomAPI/etc/module.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="RH_CustomAPI" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> **Step 3** : Create the **webapi.xml** file in the **app/code/RH/CustomAPI/etc** folder and paste the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/getsortorder" method="GET">
        <service class="RH\CustomAPI\Api\GetSortOrderInterface" method="getSortOrderData"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="admin"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

> **Step 4** : Create the **di.xml** file in **app/code/RH/CustomAPI/etc/** for API Interface file. So, paste the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="RH\CustomAPI\Api\GetSortOrderInterface" type="RH\CustomAPI\Model\GetSortOrder" />
</config>
```

> **Step 5** : Define **getSortOrderData()** method in the interface file. Create **GetSortOrderInterface.php** file in the **app/code/RH/CustomAPI/Api/** folder and paste the below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace RH\CustomAPI\Api;

interface GetSortOrderInterface {
    /**
     * Returns sort order list
     *
     * @api
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSortOrderData();
}
```

> **Step 6** : Define **getSortOrderData()** in model file. Create **GetSortOrder.php** file in the **app/code/RH/CustomAPI/Model/** folder and paste the below code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace RH\CustomAPI\Model;

use RH\CustomAPI\Api\GetSortOrderInterface;

class GetSortOrder implements GetSortOrderInterface {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
     */
    private $catalogConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    private $escaper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper    $escaper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
    }

    /**
     * Return array of Sort By List of Options of category products list page
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSortOrderData() {
        $sortOrder = $this->_catalogConfig->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
        $custom_array = [];
        foreach ($sortOrder as $key => $value) {
            $custom_array[] = $this->escaper->escapeHtml(__($value));
        }
        return $custom_array;
    }
}
```

Now, execute {base_url}/rest/V1/getsortorder url to run API.

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rohan Nice explanation.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy Coding :)